# find the first FVG or a pattern in the given session in Pinescript

Tags: pattern-matching, pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to detect the first FVG in a given session of the day, I can successfully detect FVGs in chart but I am having trouble trying to detect the first ones.

for e.g. detect the first FVG today for session between 10:00 am to 12:00 pm

I can detect FVG so you can try to explain in any way I could match the first pattern in given session

I have tried searching the internet but could not find any way to achieve this functionality.